# Running JAR with maven-dependencies not contained in this JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar

So i have a following problem:

I have a maven-project with several maven-dependencies. When i run `mvn install` it'll be packaged as .jar and the .jar together with the .pom-File will be placed inside my maven-repository. Now, this .jar does not contain other dependencies (and is also not supposed to!). Now, given that i have all the dependencies needed installed in my maven repository (which obviously maven will take care of), how can i run this jar on the command line without setting the classpath to point to every damn jar in the maven-repository? Is there any other way? `mvn exec:java` only seems to work within the maven-source directory, where it looks for the "pom.xml". But after installing, "pom.xml" becomes "name-version.pom" and i have a .jar instead of direct source/class-files. Is there any other way to point `mvn exec:java` to work with the .jar and .pom-File within the maven repository? Or maybe some other and better approach to do so?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT1: I'll just put my comment from below in here to avoid further misunderstandings:

I do not want to put the dependency jars somewhere. I want to use the repository maven already takes care of.Theoretically given, that i have ALL libraries i will ever need already in my local maven repository. I want to be able to download any other maven project, that might be using some of the libraries i already have installed in my local repository, also install it using "maven install", then remove the source i downloaded and then execute the .jar created by maven and tell java or maven (depending on what the best approach is) to look for the dependencies of that project in my local maven repository.
I hope i made it clear enough :)

EDIT 2: So i decided to use `mvn install` to install the projects into my local .m2 repo and also keep the projects unpackaged in some defined folder.Then i can just call `mvn exec:java` inside those projects to run them and maven will resolve all the dependencies for me.

Comment: Do you want to build a bundle whit all dependencies contained artifact that you can run anywhere ?

Comment: No. As i said: "Now, this .jar does not contain other dependencies (and is also not supposed to!)". I want and need it to be without the dependencies. This is just an example scenario. In the real case i'll clone some other users maven-projects and run it on my machine and i don't want to store the same library 100 times on my server.

Comment: You simply cannot do it without including the dependencies within your jar if you want to make your artifact executable.

Comment: Use eclipse or other IDE, import or clone as maven project from IDE and build and run, the IDE will resolve all maven dependencies from m2 repository.  That if does not matter to you do it in that way..

Comment: IDE is out of question cause this has to happen automatically (called by other script).

Answer (score 0):

You may exclude some dependency that you don't want to be in your project like this -

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

For more information you may check the [link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Comment: I might have been not clear enough about what i intend to do. That's why i edited the post in the same time as you answered. Maybe it'll be clear now. Sorry but your answer doesn't help me in any way :(

Answer (score 0):

Make a Jar executable and define classpath dependencies with maven can be done using maven-jar-plugin to create a manifest file. The manifest file is usually used for that

example

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>

                            <!-- It define the classpath dependencies -->
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>

                            <!-- it makes the jar executable -->
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>

                        <!-- it define some entries about your artifact -->
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Maven>Maven ${maven.version}</Build-Maven>
                            <Build-Java>${java.version}</Build-Java>
                            <Build-OS>${os.name}</Build-OS>
                            <Build-Label>${project.version}</Build-Label>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When you run the command mvn package|install, the following meta-inf/manifest.mf file will be created and added into the Jar.

If you need the dependency jar be in somewhere, that can be done easily, you will use maven-dependency-plugin to copy project dependencies to somewhere you want. you can copy into your project build directory into the manifest prefix folder defined

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.1</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>copy-dependencies</id>
       <phase>package</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>
                      ${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/
                </outputDirectory>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

all dependencies will be in `{project}/target/dependency-jars/`

That approach not include any dependency into the jar all will be out the jar in somewhere you define.

You can configurate your projects using this approach as you need

whit this approach you only have to do mvn clean install and execute your jar

I hope this aproach be the solution that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I still feel like i wasn't clear enough about what i need. I do not want to put the dependency jars somewhere. I want to use the repository maven already takes care of.

Comment: Damn, i wanted to make a line break and posted the comment already :) So here's the rest: 

Theoretically given, that i have ALL libraries i will ever need already in my local maven repository i want to be able to download any other maven project, that might be using some of the libraries i already have installed in my local repository, also install it using "maven install", then remove the source i downloaded and then execute the .jar created by maven and tell java or maven (depending on what the best approach is) to look for the dependencies of that project in my local maven repository.